# What's the best way to start the 100m sprint?

Tags: running, track-and-field

I'm trying to figure out whether starting the 100m sprint crouched like they do in the olympics is better than starting it standing. I thought maybe that's just a "sport rule", not something that actually makes the race faster. If you can link me actual videos or experiments I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A crouched start is more effective than a standing start as it places the sprinter in a position to move the center of gravity rapidly well ahead of the feet and thus the runner must accelerate very quickly or else fall.

Here is [a wonderful article](http://www.charliefrancis.com/community/showthread.php?19572-The-sprint-start) with a study comparing both, the standing and crouching styles, giving details at each milestone.

Comment: Good answer. My anecdote, not worth its own answer: when I was learning the sport, a coach demonstrated the need for blocks by having us watch people doing a standing start. Invariably the first thing a runner does in a standing start is *rock backward* away from the starting line. The blocks force a runner into forward motion immediately.